# Laravel - Usar OR dentro do where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou usando o comando `->cont` para contar o numero de retorno, e para isso coloquei um condição usando o `->WHERE` porem quando tento colocar um `||` na condição ele da erro procurei e n consigo achar a resposta.

codigo que estou usando:

```
$numrow1=DB::table('teste') 
                ->where('IdDesafiante','=',15 )
                        ->count();
```

como ja tentei:

```
 $numrow1=DB::table('teste') 
                    ->where('IdDesafiante','=',15) ||
                       ->where('IdDesafiante','=',16)
                            ->count();
```

segundo modo:

```
  $numrow1=DB::table('teste') 
                        ->where('IdDesafiante','=',15 ||'IdDesafiante','=',16)
                                ->count();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `orWhere` para fazer `or` e outro `where` apenas para fazer `and`.

```
$numrow1=DB::table('teste') 
   ->where('IdDesafiante', '=', 15)
   ->orWhere('IdDesafiante', '=', 16)
   ->count();
```

Usar o `||` nesse caso não é correto, não é semântico e não tem lógica. O Laravel é orientado a objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisar de mais "orWheres", ou tiver uma única fonte de dados sendo manipulada para realizar a montagem da query você também pode optar pelo `whereIn`:

```
$numrow1=DB::table('teste') 
   ->whereIn('IdDesafiante', array(15,16,17,18,19))
   ->count();
```